# ggplot - function for graph styling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently created some graphs in R ggplot, everything works fine except my code that is bit messy since that for each graph im using this styling

```
theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size=9),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.25, 'cm'),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(hjust = 0),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0.5)
  )
```

Is it possible to recreate this piece of code as function that I can apply for each graph?

Comment: Assign it to `mytheme` and do `p + mytheme`? I don't know why you need a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can only use it as a `theme()` and paste it in every graph you want.

Comment: well a thought the same but i can't

Comment: @ZcelaAnonymní What do you mean, you can't? Is it that you must make it into a function, or you don't want to use it as in `theme` ?

Comment: This is directly false; `theme()` always returns a list of its arguments, which can be appended to any ggplot2 or theme object.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
my_theme <- function(){
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size=9),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.25, 'cm'),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(hjust = 0),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0.5)
  ) 
}
```

and then, given a plot `p` you just have to do

```
p + my_theme()
```

Comment: You don't even have to create it as a function. You can directly assign `mytheme <- theme(...)` and then add that to your ggplot2 plot.

Comment: Sure, but author is asking for a function, I'm giving a function.He may have some implicit reasons for wanting specificly a function.