# R - Inserting function into ggplot for modifying axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like my ggplots to have the axis always start at 0, so I use this code within my ggplot to do it :

```
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,max(df$A)), ylim = c(0,max(df$B))) +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
```

As a full reproducible example:

```
df = tibble(A = sample(1:100,100, replace = TRUE), B = seq(1,100))

df  %>% 
    filter(A > 30)  %>% 
    ggplot(aes(A, B)) +
        geom_point() +
        coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,max(df$A)), ylim = c(0,max(df$B))) +
        scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

Now, those 3 lines are a pain to remember, and quite bloated.

Is there a way I can put those 3 lines into a function, and call it within the ggplot whenever I want to limit my axis?

I saw this link:

[ggplot - function for graph styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160253/ggplot-function-for-graph-styling)

Which you can use a function for the theme() part, but I am not sure how to do it for just those 3 lines I put above i.e. coord_cartesian, scale_x etc.

I.e. I want to do something like this:

```
df  %>% 
    filter(A > 30)  %>% 
    ggplot(aes(A, B)) +
        geom_point() +
        fix_the_axis()
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why not just use `+ xlim(0, NA) + ylim(0, NA)`?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately doesnt do exactly what I want. It still leaves that padding around the 0, which is made more pronounced when you have a border around the chart :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return a list with the 3 elements and add that to your plot (`ggplot` understands list arguments):

```
zero_line <- function() {
   list(expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0),
        scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)),
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)))
}

df  %>% 
    filter(A > 30)  %>% 
    ggplot(aes(A, B)) +
        geom_point() +
        zero_line()
```

[image: Scatterplot]

Comment: Exactly what I want, thank you thothal; this is going to save me a lot of time!

Comment: Very nice! Much cleaner than my approach.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how exactly you would go about it using the `+` annotation, but here is one approach:
Defining the function:

```
fix_axis = function(df_plot) {
  df_plot +
    expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
}
```

Now there are two ways I see to apply it that are both not as smooth as using the `+` annotation:

Using a bit awkward brackets:

```
df_plot_fixed = (df  %>% 
    filter(A > 30)  %>% 
    ggplot(aes(A, B)) +
        geom_point()) %>%
        fix_axis()
```

Using an extra line for the function call:

```
df_plot_fixed = df  %>% 
    filter(A > 30)  %>% 
    ggplot(aes(A, B)) +
        geom_point()

df_plot_fixed = df_plot_fixed %>%
  fix_axis()
```

These do what you want them to do and are maybe a bit smoother than always adding the three lines separately, but still not the perfect solution I assume.

This is the resulting plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great! :)